Classical probability
I'm a student in high school. I have come across the question ' Jacob buys 10 packets of detergent of brand 'ALICE' having a ticket with a letter of brand name imprinted on it under the scheme if he brings back all the letters of Alice he will get one packet free. Find probability he gets exactly one packet free'.
I tried to solve the question, and got the sample space to be $5^{10}$ which is totally incorrect. I assumed there were $5$ possibilities for every bag, and the total amount of possibilities would result to $5^{10}$. Though the solution I saw had the sample space $1001$ or (14 choose 1)

I think it makes perfect sense to model this by looking at $10-$tuples of letters.  At least that has the property that each tuple is equally probable.  I think, however, that it will be easier if you think in terms of the number of letters $J$ has seen.  Thus, after the first purchase, $J$ has definitely seen one letter.  After the second, he'll have seen $1$ or $2$ letters with known probabilities, and so on.

I read “$14$ choose $1$” which I guessed you were talking about $\displaystyle{14 \choose 1}$ which has the $\LaTeX$ code $\verb*{14 \choose 1}*$. You can change it whenever it was my mistake.

It should br $\ {14\choose10}\ $ or $\ {14\choose4}\ ,$ the number of multisets of cardinality $\ 10\ $ of objects selected from a set of $\ 5\ .$

Welcome to MathSE.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Try a simpler version: brand "AL" with four purchases.  The denominator is $2^4=16$ not ${5 \choose 1}$ or ${5 \choose 4}=5$, since the $5$ possible patterns of letters  are not equally likely.

To do it your way:
I am, of course, assuming that each letter is equally likely to appear.
First, we ignore the restriction that $J$ should only get one free one.
Consider the entire sample space, of $5^{10}$ $10-$tuples of letters.  Each of these is equally probable, so we just need to count those which have all $5$ characters.
We'll proceed by Inclusion-Exclusion.  There are $\binom 5k\times (5-k)^{10}$ patterns which are missing $k$ specified characters, so the number of $10-$tuples which aren't missing any characters is $$\sum_{k=0}^{5}(-1)^k\times \binom 5k\times (5-k)^{10}=5103000$$
Thus the desired probability is $$\frac {5103000}{5^{10}}=.5225472$$
Now, we have over estimated the answer in that we are also counting those cases in which $J$ gets two free ones.  The only way to do that is to get each letter exactly twice, there are $$\binom {10}2\times \binom 82\times \binom 62\times \binom 42\times \binom 22=113400$$ ways to do that.  Thus the probability of getting two free ones is $$\frac {113400}{5^{10}}=.01161216$$  Making the final answer to the question $$.5225472-.01161216 = .51093504$$

The answer given is 125/1001 or ( 9 choose 4) -1/ (14 choose 4) @lulu

That seems far too low.

Ah, I didn't catch the part of the problem that said "exactly" one free one.  My calculation counts those cases with $2$ free ones.  Of course, it's hard to get two free ones so I still think the official answer is too low.

The answer might be incorrect, I'm not exactly sure. But I still don't really understand how to solve it. Can you elaborate a bit on the inclusion exclusion principle. I know the basics, I just don't understand why you used it here

I have corrected my post to include that condition.  I note that my answer is still about $\frac 12$, far from the official solution.

I used it to pursue the method you proposed.  Again, I';d have done it recursively (I did that, and got the same result for the first case of the problem).  You take the $5^{10}$ sample space and first subtract the $5\times 4^{10}$ tuples that are missing $1$ specified character, then add back the $\binom 52\times 3^{10}$ tuples that are missing two specified characters and so on.

Worth noting that the recursive method is not well suited for the constraint.  In the end, I think the method I wrote out might be close to optimal.  unless I have misunderstood the problem, of course.  I simulated it to confirm the result but  the official solution is so far from what I get that possibly there is a misunderstanding.

I got it ,thanks.

You can simulate this yourself.  With a computer if you know how, or just with a regular die.  If you do it with the die, you'll have to discard the throws that come up $6$ so it's a bit inefficient (unless you happen to have a $5$ sided fair die) but it's not too bad.

@Meth See this article for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see this answer for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion formula.

The answer given—namely  $\ \frac{{9\choose4}-1}{{14\choose4}}\ $—is the ratio of the number of multisets of cardinality $10$ of the letters that contain at least one of each letter but not exactly two of each letter to the total number of multisets of cardinality $10$.  So it looks like the official "solution" is assuming that each multiset is equally likely to occur, which, of course, is nonsense (despite the fact that I  initially made exactly the same nonsensical assumption when I started to write up an answer).

@lonzaleggiera I actually rehabilitated your approach, in my answer.

@Meth Re using Inclusion-Exclusion, if you follow the syntax in my 2nd posted link, let $~S~$ denote the set of all collections of $~10~$ elements from the set $~{ ~A, ~L, ~I, ~C, ~E  ~},~$ sampling with replacement, where order of selection is deemed relevant.  Let $~S_1~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ that is missing the letter $~A.~$  Let $~S_2~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ that is missing the letter $~L,~$ and so forth.  Then, the desired computation is $$\left{ ~| ~ S ~| - | ~S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_5 ~| ~\right} \div | ~S ~|.$$

@Meth The above comment represents the analysis in lulu's answer as represented by the 2nd Inclusion-Exclusion article that I linked to.  The computation represents the first computation performed by lulu.  lulu then refined the computation to adjust for the fact that the specific selection $~{ ~A, A, L, L, I, I, C, C, E, E ~},~$ where the letters are occurring in any order, must be rejected.

@lonzaleggiera  good catch!

@user2661923 I understand now

Alternative approach:
This approach uses Stars and Bars theory, in a somewhat convoluted manner, to attack the problem.  On the one hand, I consider the Stars and Bars approach to be significantly inferior to the Inclusion-Exclusion approach, for this particular problem.
On the other hand, force-fitting Stars and Bars theory to this problem may expand the problem solver's intuition into the pitfalls of using Stars and Bars to attack probability problems.

Stars and Bars theory, which is discussed here and
here, is usually rejected as a viable approach to a probability problem, because the enumerated solutions are not equiprobable.
So, when using the Stars and Bars approach, you have to separate the solutions into groups and attach the appropriate weight to each group.  The weight will represent the relative likelihood of a solution from one group occurring versus a solution from another group.
The $~5^{10}~$ expression provides a convenient expression for the sample space.  In this sample space, the order that the letters are selected is regarded as relevant.  So, the enumeration of the number of favorable selections must consistently adopt the same convention.

Label the letters so that 'A' is $~L_1,~$ 'L' is $~L_2,~ \cdots,~$ 'E' is $~L_5.~$
For $~i \in \{1,2,3,4,5\},~$ let $~x_i~$ denote the number of times that the letter $~L_i~$ was received.  Consider the number of solutions to

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 10.$

$x_1, ~x_2 \cdots, ~x_5 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$


By Stars and Bars theory, the enumeration is $~\displaystyle \binom{[10 - 5] + 4}{4} = \binom{9}{4} = 126.$
The question is, what in the world do you do with such a number?
The first thing to do is to recognize that this represents the number of distributions where there is at least one complete set received.  This means that you have to deduct the $~(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (2,2,2,2,2)~$ solution which represents that exactly two complete sets were received.
Then, you have to partition the $~126 - 1 = 125~$ remaining solutions into groups, where the solutions in each group are assigned the same scalar.  This scalar must accommodate that the order that the letters were assigned is deemed relevant.
To facilitate this discussion, given any set of non-negative integers $~x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5,~$ such that $~x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 10,~$ let $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5}~$ denote $~\dfrac{10!}{x_1! \times x_2! \times \cdots \times x_5!}.$
Consider the following illustration:
The ordered triple $~(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (3,2,2,2,1)~$ represents that in the $~10~$ receipt positions, the three occurrences of letter $~L_1~$ could have occurred in any one of $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{3}~$ positions.  Then, of the $~7~$ remaining positions, the two occurrences of letter $~L_2~$ could have occurred in any one of $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{2}~$ positions.
Continuing in this way, you see that the $~(3,2,2,2,1)~$ solution must be assigned to a group where every element in that group will be assigned the scalar of
$$\binom{10}{3,2,2,2,1} = \frac{10!}{3! \times (2!)^3} = \frac{10!}{48}.$$

In effect, you are examining each of the distinct ways of integer partitioning the number $~10~$ into exactly $~5~$ positive terms, where the specific partition of $~10 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2~$ is rejected.
These are :

$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (6,1,1,1,1)~$ where the values assigned to the variables $~x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_5~$ may be permuted. 
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{1}~$ ways of selecting which letter will be be received $~6~$ times, so there are $~5~$ solutions in this group. 
Further, each solution needs to be assigned the scalar of 
$~\displaystyle \binom{10}{6,1,1,1,1} = 5040~$ to accommodate that the order of selection of the letters is regarded as relevant. 
So, the computation assigned to this partition is
$5 \times 5040 = 25200.$ 

$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (5,2,1,1,1)~$ where the values assigned to the variables $~x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_5~$ may be permuted. 
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{1} = 20 ~$ ways of selecting which letter will be be received $~5~$ times, and then which letter will be received $~2~$ times, so there are $~20~$ solutions in this group. 
Further, each solution needs to be assigned the scalar of 
$~\displaystyle \binom{10}{5,2,1,1,1} = 15120~$ to accommodate that the order of selection of the letters is regarded as relevant.
So, the computation assigned to this partition is
$20 \times 15120 = 302400.$ 

$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (4,3,1,1,1)~$ where the values assigned to the variables $~x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_5~$ may be permuted. 
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{1} = 20 ~$ ways of selecting which letter will be be received $~4~$ times, and then which letter will be received $~3~$ times, so there are $~20~$ solutions in this group. 
Further, each solution needs to be assigned the scalar of 
$~\displaystyle \binom{10}{4,3,1,1,1} = 25200~$ to accommodate that the order of selection of the letters is regarded as relevant.
So, the computation assigned to this partition is
$20 \times 25200 = 504000.$ 

$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (4,2,2,1,1)~$ where the values assigned to the variables $~x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_5~$ may be permuted. 
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{2} = 30 ~$ solutions in this group. 
Further, each solution needs to be assigned the scalar of 
$~\displaystyle \binom{10}{4,2,2,1,1} = 37800.$ 
So, the computation assigned to this partition is
$30 \times 37800 = 1134000.$ 

$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (3,3,2,1,1)~$ where the values assigned to the variables $~x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_5~$ may be permuted. 
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2} \times \binom{3}{1} = 30 ~$ solutions in this group. 
Further, each solution needs to be assigned the scalar of 
$~\displaystyle \binom{10}{3,3,2,1,1} = 50400.$ 
So, the computation assigned to this partition is
$30 \times 50400= 1512000.$ 

$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (3,2,2,2,1)~$ where the values assigned to the variables $~x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_5~$ may be permuted. 
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{3} = 20 ~$ solutions in this group. 
Further, each solution needs to be assigned the scalar of 
$~\displaystyle \binom{10}{3,2,2,2,1} = 75600.$ 
So, the computation assigned to this partition is
$20 \times 75600 = 1512000.$ 



Notice that $~6~$ different subsets of solutions were identified, with the number of solutions in each subset identified as $~5, ~20, ~20, ~30, ~30, ~20.~$
So, the Stars and Bars analysis sanity-checks that all $~125~$ solutions have been grouped and then assigned the appropriate scalar.
The sum of the computations assigned to each group is
$$25200 + 302400 + 504000 + 1134000 + 1512000 + 1512000 = 4989600.$$
So, the final computation is
$$\frac{4989600}{5^{10}} = 0.51093504.$$

As @lonza leggiera has remarked in a comment, the book answer has computed favorable ways and total ways using stars and bars, which is inappropriate as stars and bars does not yield equiprobable outcomes.
It is a case of distinct objects into distinct bins, which can be tackled by inclusion-exclusion or using the multinomial distribution.
This answer  uses a streamlined version of the multinomial distribution, using the format
[Lay Down Pattern] x [Permute pattern]
There are $6$ allowable patterns,
$61111,\;52111,\;43111,\;42211,\;33211,\;and\; 32221$, with pattern $22222$ ignored as we are to collect only one copy each of the correct letter.
As an example, for pattern $33211$, the computation would be
$\frac{10!}{3!3!2!1!1!}\times\frac{5!}{2!1!2!}$, which, by combining the terms of the numerator, and removing the $1!'s$ from the denominator, can be condesed to $\frac{10!5!}{3!3!2!2!2!}$
Proceeding thus for each listed case sequentially, we get
$ {10!5!\left[\frac{1}{6!4!} + \frac{1}{5!2!3!} +\frac{1}{4!3!3!}+\frac{1}{4!2!2!2!2!}+\frac{1}{3!3!2!2!2!}+\frac{1}{3!2!2!2!3!}\;\right]}$
$= 4989600$
and $Pr = \dfrac{4989600}{5^{10}}, \approx 0.51$

As an extended comment to demonstrate that lulu's answer is better than the solution you saw, here is a simulation in R:
fullnames <- function(n, name){
  letters <- sample(name, n, replace=TRUE)
  return(min(table(factor(letters, levels=name))))
  }

set.seed(2024)
cases <- 10^6
purchases <- 10
Alice <- c("A","L","I","C","E")
fullsets <- replicate(cases, fullnames(purchases, Alice))
table(fullsets)/cases
# fullsets
#        0        1        2 
# 0.477705 0.510688 0.011607 

which, allowing for simulation noise, is consistent with lulu's and user2661923's $\frac{4662625}{5^{10}}=0.47745280$, $\frac{4989600}{5^{10}}=0.51093504$, $\frac{113400}{5^{10}}=0.01161216$.
The simulation code would work equally well with any other name with no repeated letters and any other number of purchases.
An easier example might be "Jo" with $4$ purchases, where the probabilities of $0$ full names (i.e. purchasing JJJJ or OOOO) is $\frac2{16}$, exactly $1$ full name (i.e. JJJO, JJOJ, JOJJ, OJJJ, JOOO, OJOO, OOJO, OOJJ) is $\frac{8}{16}$, and $2$ full names (i.e. JJOO, JOJO, JOOJ, OJJO, OJOJ, OOJJ) is $\frac{6}{16}$.  Having a denominator of ${5 \choose 1} =  {5 \choose 4} = 5$ rather than $2^4=16$ (based on sorting to JJJJ, JJJO, JJOO, JOOO, OOOO, and thinking these might be equally likely)  is going to give the wrong answer.
